# How to rotate a <select> field through all its <options> using jQuery (Firefox only issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

It's almost done but I can't figure out why this code stop working (rotating the selected option) after completing the first cycle.

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="jsfiddle-container" class="form-group col-sm-12">
    <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
        <select name="medio" id="medio" class="form-control text-center" required>
            <option value="" selected>Forma de Pago</option>
            <option value="tc">Tarjeta de Crédito</option>
            <option value="cash">Efectivo</option>
            <option value="cheq">Cheque</option>
        </select>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button id="btn-medio-plus" class="btn btn-info" type="button" tabindex="-1">Change
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#btn-medio-plus').click( function() {
     var actual = $('#medio option:selected');
     var actualIndex = actual.index();
     var nextIndex = ( actualIndex + 1 == $('#medio option').length ) ? 0 : actualIndex + 1;
     var next = $('#medio option').eq( nextIndex );

     actual.removeAttr('selected');
     next.attr('selected', true);
});
```

And here is the jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/swordf1zh/zue7ghcw/3/

I'm new into Javascript so I would really appreciate an explanation of how to make the code work and why it's not working as expected right now.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems to work just fine for me ?

Comment: whola...works fine for me too...!!

Comment: It works in Chrome, but not in Firefox 31. It goes through all of them and then it blocks on `Forma de Pago`.

Comment: OK, I just notice that it's working in Chrome and even in Explorer but not in Firefox... any hints of what could be happening?

Comment: btw nice and detailed explanation just found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a FF bug to me. Still, you should use `.prop("selected")` instead of `.attr("selected")` to change the selected state of the element*.

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/zue7ghcw/5/)

* This is the recommended method for manipulating *properties* of elements such as `disabled`, `checked` and `selected`.

Comment: `attr` worked with jQuery <= 1.8, but not with jQuery >= 1.9, but it's better to user `prop`.

Answer (score 4):

How about this?  The modulus operator is used in favor of an if statement and the code is reduced to:

```
$('#btn-medio-plus').click( function() {
    var opt_l = $( "#medio option" );
    var opt_s = $( "#medio option:selected" );
    var i = $( opt_s ).index() + 1;
    $( opt_l[ i % opt_l.length ] ).prop( "selected", true );   
});
```

This appears to work in both Firefox and Chrome.

[**Modified Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zue7ghcw/10/)

Comment: Hey thank you very much, I just learned with your answer that if the divisor is bigger then the dividend then the value of the modulo is the same as the dividend. I will keep this trick in mind when working with array indexes.